# NSPredicate Format Equivalent to SQL query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have two tables: table1 and table2. What would be the `NSPredicate` format equivalent to the following SQL query?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where table1.a NOT IN (SELECT table2.b from table2)
```

Comment: Core Data is not a database. You cannot translate arbitrary SQL into a core data fetch request. Go re-read the documentation a couple of times. Until then, you *will* be confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can get a list of b values from table2 then do something like this...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (a in %@)", listOfBValues];
```

Comment: thank you Simon but please see my query in which i need list of values from table1 where the attribute 'a' not presented in a list of values from table2 ..how can in in cooperate this in NSPredicate ????

Comment: @Rajesh Simon addressed that.  You need to get all of the `table.b` values first, and then substitute those in to the `NSPredicate`.